# check and uncheck buttons in table view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift4

I am new to ios swift4 and I just create check and uncheck buttons in table view controller and my task is to select the items in the table with the check button and I want to uncheck those selected checked on clicking uncheck button.Help me to solve this

Comment: What you have tried to achieve this?

Comment: I suggest you to have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then open the question again with more info :).

Comment: You can set a different tag for each button. On click one of these button, get its tag, and then iterate over all button and uncheck those which their tag is different than the clicked button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `daysRemainderTableView` take imageview with name `daysSelectionimageView`.This is example to select and deselect rows in tableviewcell .

```
     @IBOutlet weak var daysRemainderTableView: UITableView!

         var days = ["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"]

var selectedDaysArray = [Int]() 

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return days.count
        }
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RemainderDaysCell", for: indexPath)as! RemainderDaysCell
                cell.remainderDaysLabel.text = "\(days[indexPath.row])"


                if selectedDaysArray.contains(indexPath.row){
                    cell.daysSelectionimageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "selectedImage")
                }else{
                    cell.daysSelectionimageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ring")
                }
                return cell
            }

            func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
                if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? RemainderDaysCell
                {
                    if selectedDaysArray.isEmpty{
                        self.selectedDaysArray = [Int]()
                    }
                    if selectedDaysArray.contains(indexPath.row){
                        if let indexElement = selectedDaysArray.index(of: indexPath.row){
                            cell.daysSelectionimageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ring")
                            selectedDaysArray.remove(at: indexElement)
                        }
                    }else{
                        cell.daysSelectionimageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "selectedImage")
                        selectedDaysArray.append(indexPath.row)
                    }
                }
            }
```

I am checking `selectedDaysArray` in cellforrow at indexpath and didSelectRow ai indexpath ,if selectedDaysArray has selected index i am removing element if it is not i am appending indexemement to selectedDaysArray.

Comment: Thank u this is very helpful for me